# ffmpeg produces M4A that iTunes can not stream as a podcast (iOS Podcasts app can)

Tags: ffmpeg, itunes, podcasts

iTunes can play such M4A only after downloading. I found another podcast with M4A and iTunes stream those episodes correctly.

My command is

`ffmpeg -i input.ogg  output.m4a`

Result:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-4) 20170820
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'input.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:04.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 35 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ipod, to 'output.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
size=      35kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate=  69.5kbits/s speed=36.4x
video:0kB audio:34kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.260525%
[aac @ 0x56fc940] Qavg: 11478.364
```

Answer (score 2):

I need more carefully read documentation...

Quote from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#Progressivedownload:

> By default the MP4 muxer writes the 'moov' atom after the audio stream
>   ('mdat' atom) at the end of the file. This results in the user
>   requiring to download the file completely before playback can occur.
>   Relocating this moov atom to the beginning of the file can facilitate
>   playback before the file is completely downloaded by the client.
>
> You can do this with the -movflags +faststart option:
>
> ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart output.m4a
>   You can also use this option on existing MP4/M4A files. Since the
>   audio is simply being stream copied there is no re-encoding occurring,
>   just re-muxing, so therefore there is no quality loss:
>
> ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.m4a